# Open Settings application on Unity iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, settings, launch

I am in need of a way to make the user is taken to the Settings application to disable the multitasking gestures. I know that in iOS 8 you can launch the Settings application programmatically through the URL in Objective-C:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
```

But I do not know how to get this URL in Unity to use with Application.OpenURL()

Comment: Please, don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It is generally a good idea to read the tag's description before using it.

Comment: Sorry, I will pay more attention next time

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to write a tiny iOS plugin for that, here is more information about it: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

And here is your solution, ask if something should be unclear.

**Script/Example.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example 
{
    public void OpenSettings()
    {
        #if UNITY_IPHONE
            string url = MyNativeBindings.GetSettingsURL();
            Debug.Log("the settings url is:" + url);
            Application.OpenURL(url);
        #endif
    }
}
```

**Plugins/MyNativeBindings.cs**

```
public class MyNativeBindings 
{
    #if UNITY_IPHONE
        [DllImport ("__Internal")]
        public static extern string GetSettingsURL();

        [DllImport ("__Internal")]
        public static extern void OpenSettings();
    #endif
}
```

**Plugins/iOS/MyNativeBindings.mm**

```
extern "C" {
    // Helper method to create C string copy
    char* MakeStringCopy (NSString* nsstring)
    {
        if (nsstring == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        // convert from NSString to char with utf8 encoding
        const char* string = [nsstring cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if (string == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }

        // create char copy with malloc and strcpy
        char* res = (char*)malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
        strcpy(res, string);
        return res;
    }

    const char* GetSettingsURL () {
         NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
         return MakeStringCopy(url.absoluteString);
    }

    void OpenSettings () {
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try also print this URL to get it and use with Application.OpenURL() to not have to use a plugin ;)

Comment: it's possible to print the URL and open it with Application.OpenURL(), but you still need a plugin to get the URL, because Apple might change the URL and you app will break with a hardcoded URL. (i will share that code tomorrow)

Comment: i added a GetSettingsURL() method

Comment: I will accept your answer, thanks. Hope that Unity team provide a method to get this URL in C#

Comment: I don't think the Unity Team will add this, they don't like platform specific code.

Answer (score 3):

Using idea of JeanLuc, I create a empty XCode project and print the string constant `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` and used in Unity with Application.OpenURL() to not have to use a plugin. Works very nice.

The value for constant `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` is: "app-settings:" (without quotas).

Use: `Application.OpenURL("app-settings:")` to open directly from unity

WARNING: The use of hardcoded strings is dangerous and can break your code if Apple change the value of constant `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`. Its just a workaround while Unity does not add a constant for reference in C# code.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No need to make a plugin. It's just 'Application.OpenURL("app-settings:") '